# Modificar CSS según el tamaño de la pantalla

Tags: css, html5

Básicamente tengo dos menús y quiero que uno aparezca cuando el ancho de pantalla sea grande y desaparezca el otro y viceversa, para tener un menú para PC y otro para móviles pero por alguna razón cuando estrecho la pantalla desaparece el menú de PC pero no aparece el de móviles. Este es el código del CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1490px) {
    #menu-categorias{
        display: none;
    }

    #menu-up{
        display:block;
    }
}
```

El menu-categorias funciona perfectamente, desaparece al estrechar la pantalla pero el menu-up no aparece.

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Claro, porque la lógica está mal. Deberías tener `#menu-up` siempre en `display: block` y `#menu-categorias` siempre en `display: none`, sin ninguna *Media Query*. Y establecer la *Media Query* con `min-width` donde vas a cambiar el `display` de ambos. Prueba eso y comenta el resultado.

Comment: Sólo aparece el menú up

Comment: Por eso, el media query modifica lo que ya existe. Si pones la base primero, el media query lo que hará será modificar lo que ya existe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta de la siguiente forma:

```
/*Primero la vista por defecto de los menus*/
#menu-categorias{ 
    display:none;
}
#menu-up{
    display:block;
}

/*Una vez alcance los 1490px realizas el cambio*/
@media screen and (min-width: 1490px) {
    #menu-categorias{
        display: block;
    }

    #menu-up{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Así si me funciona perfecto, ¡Muchas gracias!